# Updating table with DISTINCT function from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct

I've created a new table with a few columns, all of which start out as NULL.

I have another table called "items" with a column called "item_type".  This column contains a lot of duplicates.  I want to take the values generated by `DISTINCT(item_type)` and use them to fill one of the new empty columns in my new table.  I tried this, but I can't get it to work:

```
UPDATE new_table
SET new_column = DISTINCT(items.item_type)
FROM items
```

Do I need to generate a new table and then join the two?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?. Also, how do you relate the `items` on your old table with your new table?, what are the rest of the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better populate the table in such a way:

```
INSERT INTO new_table(new_column)
SELECT DISTINCT(items.item_type)
FROM items
```

**or**

if table is already populated - you need to provide some behavior connecting these tables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the new table is empty:

```
INSERT new_table
SELECT DISTINCT item_type
FROM items
```